# Razor pages, return all checkboxes as a list of values

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, checkbox

I want my checkboxes in a form to return as a list of all the values for selected checkboxes

```
foreach (string url in ListOfPhotoURLs)
    {
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Input.ChosenPhotos" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="PhotosChosen" value="@url">
            <img src="@url" alt="photo from url @url" width="250">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Input.ChosenPhotos"></span>
        </div>
    }
```

Where `Input.ChosenPhotos` is type `List<string>` and when the form is submitted I want my list to be populated with all of the values (`url`) that correspond with a checked checkbox

When I run I get an error that basically says checkboxes can only return a bool or string. Not a list of strings or bools.

Problem is my list is of inderterminet length so I cant have an input model that has an individual property for each checkbox.

I'm not sure what the optimal solution is here?

Im using Razor Pages btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message said, if you use tag helper in checkbox, it only allows bool or string type property. For your scenario, you could change `asp-for` to `name` like below:

```
@foreach (string url in ListOfPhotoURLs)
{
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input name="Input.ChosenPhotos" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="PhotosChosen" value="@url">
        <img src="@url" alt="photo from url @url" width="250">
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Input.ChosenPhotos"></span>
    </div>
}
```

Backend code:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }
    public class InputModel
    {
        public string[] ChosenPhotos { get; set; }
    }
    public void OnPost()
    {
        //do your stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think Rena's answer would work, but this is the solution I found and have just implemented (before Rena's answer was posted)

https://mycodingtips.com/2021/3/23/code-snippet-to-create-a-checkboxlist-in-asp-net-core-razor-page-application

https://github.com/Melvinmz/chkBoxSnippet